# Сборник слов для изучения

Tags: python, база-данных

Начал изучать программирование, поставил себе задачу написать программу на Питоне которая поможет мне подучить английские слова связанные с программированием.
Концепция простая.

1. Создать "записную книжку" в которую буду вносить слово и его перевод. Думаю нужно использовать tkinter.
2. Прикрутить базу данных или обращение к файлу.
3. Программа должна показывать случайное слово из базы и несколько вариантов ответа с проверкой правильно или нет.

Может кто сталкивался с таким кодом с комментариями.

Comment: ну... 1) можно прикрутить .ini файл (удобно и быстро редактировать) 3) зачем давать выбор, слово набранное ручками, запоминается гораздо легче *) когда-то делал похожую программу но на другом яп (если суть не в тренировках могу поискать)

Comment: Вообще, сооздание такой проограммы - хороший пример для изучения питончика. Я советую также реализовать в программе так называемый "метод интервальных повторений", суть которого такоева: если Вы правильно ответили на вопрос программы - то это слоово долго не будет у Вас спрашиваться снова. Если неправильно - то проограмма довольно соокоро зановоо спроосит Вас, чтообы понять, выучили Вы его, или нет. Также, имейте в виду, что есть многозначные слоова, у котоорых есть несколько правильных переводов.

Answer (score 2):

tkinter подходит для наброса интерфейса за 5 минут, если хочешь действительно качественный и более функциональный интерфейс, то советую pyqt с его дизайнером. Pyqt позволит без костылей работать с базами и.т.п. логику проще писать. Для изучения Pyqt надо знать классы, словари, списки, работу функций. На изучение Pyqt уйдет больше времени, чем на изучение tkinter, но этого того стоит.

Для начала изучения советую глянуть следующие ресурсы:
https://pythonworld.ru/gui/pyqt5-firstprograms.html
https://tproger.ru/translations/python-gui-pyqt/
Ну и разные видео из ютюба.

Я крайне советую не копипастить код, а полноценно изучить тему.